# flutter : how to open widget outside application based on notification?

Tags: flutter, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, overlay

I am developing a delivery application, and I need to address the following scenario: If a user receives a delivery order but is not actively using the app, I want to display a widget with buttons to notify them about the delivery request. This widget should overlay on top of other apps. Furthermore, I need to include a button within the widget for the user to accept the order. How can I achieve this?

adding a flutter widget over other apps and handle this widget.